# что такое ирбитнц?

Tags: значения

Копаясь в словаре Лопатина, натолкнулся на странное слово **Ирбитнц**.
Поиск в интернете ничего не дал.
Кто-нибудь знает, что это такое?

[lopatin.academic.ru](https://lopatin.academic.ru/46894/%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%86)
[orf.textologia.ru](https://orf.textologia.ru/definit/irbitnc/?q=532&n=46081)

Comment: Можете ли вы предоставить больше контекста?

Comment: My paper copy doesn't have this word. Where exactly did you see it and in which edition? My guess it's a typo or an OCR error for _ирбитец_ "a resident of Irbit, Russia", but it should have been cited in the plural and not capitalized.

Answer (score 4):

Совершенно очевидно, что в слове опечатка, потому что чуть ниже дается форма множественного числа, плюс рядом даются окончания и единственного тоже.

Oпиcaниe и фopмы cлoвa: иpби́тцы, -eв, *eд. -тeц, -тцa, тв. -тцeм*

То есть слово должно писаться "ирбитец". Это житель города Ирбит.

Answer (score 0):

[Большой понятный самоучитель](https://books.google.ee/books?id=MmE8EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq=%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%86&source=bl&ots=gr9BgyrGA_&sig=ACfU3U3H8omZNORgLvrwqPxqj6LYcgdsdQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix_I3p9M6DAxWaFxAIHSNlAP84FBDoAXoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%86&f=false):

> **Ирби́т**: ирбитча́не (ирби́тцы), ирбитча́нин (ирби́тец), ирбитча́нка

Это [этнохороним](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/50582) — название жителя (жителей) определённой местности, образованнное от названия этой местности (топонима).